# Xpath in Appium Using Java - Mobile App - Automation testing

Tags: java, xpath, automation, appium

I'm doing an automation testing for an App that only has XPath for the whole Mobile system as picking its elements,

what is the most efficient way to use those XPath and not falter with other elements from the same page?

Comment: I think you will need to expand this question. It's not at all clear to me what you are trying to do, or what kind of answer you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) to get the `xpath` for the locators and once you have it, you can test the xpath with the same app if it is detecting the only element that you're currently working with.

Also, please refer to the [Appium Desktop Tutorials](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/appium-desktop) for your reference.